# Findbugs SIO_SUPERFLUOUS_INSTANCEOF

Tags: java, findbugs

In my findbugs report I have a [SIO_SUPERFLUOUS_INSTANCEOF](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#SIO_SUPERFLUOUS_INSTANCEOF) correctness error in the following code section

```
/** Allow Comparison based on User-Labels */
public int compareTo(AbstractListItem o) {
    if ( !( o instanceof AbstractListItem ) ) {
        // Correctness - Unnecessary type check done using instanceof operator
        // : Method com.x.y.gui.topology.TopologyListNode.compareTo (AbstractListItem) 
        // does an unnecessary type check using instanceof operator when it 
        // can be determined statically
    return -1;
}
```

What is the correct way to statically determine the type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`public int compareTo(AbstractListItem o)` - `o` *is* an `AbstractListItem`, you don't need to check.

If you had `public int compareTo(Object o)` *then* your `instanceof` would be needed and not produce a warning.

Answer (score 2):

In your code the type of object o is already statically determined as AbstractListItem, and therefore the instanceof is unnecessary. Findbugs reported it as a warning because it may be a sign of bug, e.g., what you wanted to check was a subtype of AbstractListItem, but you'd typed AbstractListItem by mistake.